# Cocoa Touch - Detecting Motion?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is it physically possible to have the iphone camera detect motion? If so, How do you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean technically :) ? Physically it already does (in the sense of taping motion).

Technically you could use the interfaces defined in `AVFoundation.framework`, create bitmaps from selected frames and compare them. Usually you would make the images [monochromatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) (or turn them into [binary images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image), it depends on your actual project), and compare the pixels. If a particular amount of connected pixels has changed, there must have been motion.

You would convert the images color space to gray-scale to have a better performance when comparing. It depends again on your project how many shades of gray you need. The picky part is the comparing algorithm for sure. A naive method would be just to count the changed (connected) pixels (making the image gray-scale can save you a lot of false positives). You could also do a [Binary Search](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch)

Comment: Well im scanning for motion of people. So what do you recommend? Just grayscale or binary? Is there a difference?

Comment: You said use the `AVFoundation.framework` what are some method to do this that are in there?

Comment: @shorty876 To find out how to use the AVFoundation framework consider reading: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html

A binary image is just a special case of gray-scale image. A pixel there may only have one of two states. In gray-scale image a pixel would be black or white. You achieve this by setting all pixels with >= 50% brightness to white and all others to black. For tracking people i would use as many shades as possible.